# Using cast in SQL with multiple column selections

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

Basically I'd like to get this command to work:

```
$sql = "SELECT (EntryDate + TotalTime) as DataLine FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID='AA01'";
```

EntryDate is in the database as a text, but TotalTime is a Number. I need to cast TotalTime as a text, because I've noticed if I combine two differing types of values, it just blanks out the output.

I know I'm supposed to use CAST(TotalTime as XXX) but I'm not sure what I can legally cast it to (char/nchar doesn't seem to work, neither does string nor text). I always get an error of the form...

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(EntryDate + CAST(TotalTime as string) as DataLine FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID='AA01''
```

Could I get some help? Thank you!

**EDIT** I would like to note this isn't intended to add together the values of EntryDate and TotalTime together to produce a single value. I simply want it to give me the EntryDate value as well as the TotalTime value combined into a single line that would read something like:

"10/31/12 9.25"

**EDIT AGAIN** I'm sorry for not specifying before, I'm using MSSQL

Comment: check my post below, i edited it if you are using mysql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(EntryDate AS VARCHAR(25)) + CAST(TotalTime AS VARCHAR(10)) as DataLine 
FROM TimeSheet 
WHERE EmployeeID = 'AA01';
```

However, if `entrydate` is a date and the int `totaltime` is a time, it may be better to consider converting them as a datetime object by adding them as a date part to the time part depending on the RDBMS you are using. And if possible use a `DATETIME` datatype to represent both date and time parts instead of two parts. Like so:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, totaltime, entrydate)
FROM TimeSheet
WHERE EmployeeID = 'AA01';
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c6d9/6)

Comment: no need to convert EntryDate to varchar, i think TS said, it is already a text datatype

Comment: @hoser What is the type of entrydate? and what RDBMS you are using MSSQL or mysql ,..?

Comment: EntryDate is type Text. And I'm using MSSQL

Comment: @Hoser - It should work fine. Try to use `ADDDATE` function. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT EntryDate+''+CAST(TotalTime as char(25)) as DataLine FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID='AA01'";
```

MySQL

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(EntryDate,' ',CONVERT(TotalTime,char(25))) as DataLine FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID='AA01'";
```

Comment: are you using MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: It still doesn't work, giving me the same 'missing operator' error unfortunately. I tried using the MySQL version just for kicks but it told me CONCAT isn't a valid method, which I figured would happen.